# Почему функция не считывает параметр?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Всем добрый!

С терминалом пока еще на Вы, поэтому не могу разобраться.
Есть функция, которая должна принимать номер сервера из цикла:

```
function func() {
    ssh server@server$1.ru ....
}

for server in {01..03}
do 
    func $server
done
```

Упорно не считывается $server

Comment: Линукс тут ни при чём, это вопрос по шеллу, скорее всего bash

Comment: с виду всё вроде как правильно.... что именно значит «не считывается $server»?

Comment: Приведите прмер вашей 1й строчки файла желаем результат `#!/bin/bash` , `#!/bin/sh` , `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.  Приведите пример отработки скрипта.

Comment: добавьте перед символами `ssh` символы `echo ` (в конце пробел) и посмотрите на результат.

Answer (score 0):

вставил ваш код в файл, добавив только перед `ssh` вызов `echo`:

```
function func() {
    echo ssh server@server$1.ru ....
}

for server in {01..03}
do 
    func $server
done
```

и запустил:

```
$ bash файл
ssh server@server01.ru ....
ssh server@server02.ru ....
ssh server@server03.ru ....
```

вывод свидетельствует о том, что параметр отлично «считывается».

так что если ваша программа ведёт себя не так, как вы ожидаете, то либо вы ожидаете от неё не того, что есть на самом деле, либо ошибка находится совсем не в том месте, которое вы предположили (непередающийся параметр функции).

---

вообще похоже на то, что вам требуется что-нибудь вроде [gnu/parallel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gnu+parallel). благо их [много](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/admin/pdsh_parallel.html).

Comment: Делал тоже самое результат идиетичный вашему, не стал публиковать. В вопросе мало данных о том, что делает автор. Наверняка не точный скрипт в целом, исходя из того, что автор на Вы с bash.